# Why my binary search function doesn't stop when the element isn't in the list?

Tags: python, binary-search

I have the following binary search function:

```
def in_bisect(sorted_list, target):

    temp = sorted_list[:]
    low = 0 
    mid = (len(temp)-1) // 2 
    high = len(temp)-1 
    count = 0
    
    if target > temp[high] or target < temp[low]:
        return False
    
    while True:
        mid = len(temp) // 2 
        count += 1
        if target == temp[mid]:
            print("Target found in %d steps " % count)
            return True

        elif target > temp[mid]:  
            low = mid             
            temp = temp[low:]
        
        elif target < temp[mid]: 
            high = mid           
            temp = temp[:high]

    
    return False
```

It works fine when I look for an element on the given list of words. However, when I test a word that isn't on the list the loop goes to infinite!!!

I have tested it with a list of 113k+ alphabetically sorted words, and it is very efficient (or that what I'd like think at least) it finds the target in 17 steps maximum.

This is a test I did :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fin = open('words.txt')
    a = []
    for line in fin:
        a.append(line.strip())
    print(in_bisect(a,'longsome'))
```

`'longsome'` is a word in `words.txt` file, if I change it to let's say `'blahblah'` the loop goes for ever.

I would like it to return `False` immediately if there is no match.
Also, any improvement suggestions along the way is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?  Why not?

Comment: Why `while True`? Why not something like `while len(temp) > 0`? How do you expect to get out of the while loop if the word isn't actually present?

Comment: You need a test for length of `temp` being zero, one or two; then in that suite return an appropriate value depending what is in `temp`.

Comment: (you might want to change `temp = temp[low:]` to `temp = temp[low + 1:]`, and do the same in reverse for `high`. After all, you know the element you just searched is wrong, so why include it?)

Comment: The 'while True' has no break..

Comment: @ScottHunter Well, I haven't.

Comment: Can you use [the bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy `while len(temp) > 0` doesn't work either

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Thanks man, `temp = temp[low +1 : ]` and `temp = temp[:high-1]` did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no way for the while loop to break, so until we run out of the range to search for, we go on, otherwise, we break. Also, `low = mid + 1` was required as otherwise the list size won't reduce properly. Same for `high`.

```
def in_bisect(sorted_list, target):

    temp = sorted_list[:]
    low = 0 
    mid = (len(temp)-1) // 2 
    high = len(temp)-1 
    count = 0
    
    if target > temp[high] or target < temp[low]:
        return False
    
    while True:
        if len (temp) == 0:
            break
        mid = len(temp) // 2
        count += 1
        if target == temp[mid]:
            print("Target found in %d steps " % count)
            return True

        elif target > temp[mid]:  
            low = mid + 1             
            temp = temp[low:]
        
        elif target < temp[mid]: 
            high = mid - 1           
            temp = temp[:high + 1]

    
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks man, although @GreenCloakGuy did help with solving the problem in the comment above, by mentioning the list reduction issue. Thanks for both of you.